# How to extract data from mnesia backup file

Tags: erlang, mnesia, ets

**Problem statement**

I have a mnesia backup file and would like to extract values from it. There are 3 tables(to make it simple), Employee, Skills, and attendance. So the mnesia back up file contains all those data from these three tables.

Emplyee table is :

```
Empid (Key) 
Name
SkillId
AttendanceId
```

Skill table is

```
SkillId (Key)
Skill Name
```

Attendance table is

```
Code (Key)
AttendanceId
Percentage
```

**What i have tried**
I have used

`ets:foldl(Fetch,OutputFile,Table)`

Fetch : is separate function to traverse the record fetched to bring in desired output format.

OutputFile : it writes to this file

Table : name of the table

**Expecting**

I am gettig records with AttendanceId(as this is the key) where as i Want to get *code* only. It displays employee informations and attendance id.

Help me out.

Comment: How did you get your file? If with `mnesia:backup`, you should use `mnesia:restore`, or `mnesia:traverse_backup`

Comment: I am not restoring back to another mnesia database. Instead I need to extract some fields from backup to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Backup and restore is described in the mnesia user guide [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap7.html#id83771).

To read an existing backup, without restoring it, use [mnesia:traverse_backup/4](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#traverse_backup-4).

```
1> mnesia:backup(backup_file).
ok
2> Fun = fun(BackupItems, Acc) -> {[], []} end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.90072148>
3> mnesia:traverse_backup(backup_file, mnesia_backup, [], read_only, Fun, []).
{ok,[]}
```

Now add something to the Fun to get what you want.